# $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are concurrent in $\triangle ABC$. Show that lines through midpoints of $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ parallel to $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are concurrent.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are concurrent lines in $\triangle ABC$. Show that the lines through the midpoints of $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ respectively parallel to $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are concurrent.

My attempt

I tried using Ceva's theorem but not getting how to use it. Please give me a hint.

> I know this question has already been answered (for instance, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1454738/409)), but I want hint related to Ceva's or Menelaus' theorem.

Comment: Although it is not compulsory, it is always a good ides to post a diagram with questions in the field of geometry to attract help.

Comment: Even if you are looking for a solution using Ceva's theorem, see a solution using homothety [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3522173).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle, denote by $M,N,P$ the mid points of the sides opposite to $A,B,C$. Let $D$ be a point on $BC$. The parallel to $AD$ through $M$ intersects $NP$ in a point denoted by $D'$.

Construct $E',F'$ in a similar way on the sides of $\Delta MNP$.

Because $MN$, $ND'$, $D'M$ are parallel to (respectively) $AB$, $BD$, $DA$, we obtain a triangle similarity, so $D'N:DB=MN:AB=1:2$. This gives $D'N:D'P=DB:DC$.

We finally apply Ceva (and the reciprocal) in the two triangles $\Delta ABC$, $\Delta MNP$:
$$
\frac{D'N}{D'P}\cdot 
\frac{E'P}{E'M}\cdot 
\frac{F'M}{F'N} 
=
\frac{DB}{DC}\cdot 
\frac{EC}{EA}\cdot 
\frac{FA}{FB} 
=
-1\ .
$$
$\square$

---

Later edit: Quick picture inserted:

[image: Ceva application, dan_fulea, mathematics stackexchange, 3518128]

Comment: Can you pls provide a diagram..i get confused with mine

Comment: @IMO2021GOLD dan_fulea spend some time to solve and write this for you. Can you not say even thank you?

Comment: Thankyou very much...dan fulea

Comment: $MN\| AB$ because $MN$ is mid line, or because of Thales, or by the similarity of $\Delta CBA\sim\Delta CMN$. In the same manner, $NP\|BC$.