# Concurrence geometry problem

Tags: geometry

> $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent lines on $\triangle ABC$. Show that lines through the midpoints of $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively parallel to $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent.

Let $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_3$ be midpoints of $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. Lines parallel to $AD$ and $BE$ pass through $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively meet at point $O$. It suffices to prove that line from $M_3$ to $O$ is parallel to $CF$.

I am guessing that this has to do with Ceva's theorem. But I am unable to use it to prove the statement. It is really confusing because of so many lines in the figure. Kindly post your solutions.

[image]

Comment: Line $CO$ is not parallel to $CF$, hence your hint doesn't work.

Comment: Oops I drawn wrong figure But i corrected it now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the lines through the midpoints of BC,CA,AB respectively parallel to AD,BE,CF are concurrent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454738/show-that-the-lines-through-the-midpoints-of-bc-ca-ab-respectively-parallel-to-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original triangle $ABC$ and its medial triangle $M_1 M_2 M_3$ are related via a dilation $\delta$ centered at the common centroid $G$. Any dilation preserves parallel lines and concurrency, so if $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent so they are their images via $\delta$, i.e. the given lines through $M_1,M_2,M_3$.

Comment: D'Aurizo I appreciate your solution but i am not up to the level to understand your solution .Can you make it a little elementary??

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that the same question has been asked on some days before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518128) with an answer using Ceva's theorem.

**What follows is not an answer.** Just a comment and a figure on which the excellent proof by Jack D'Aurizio can be better understood.

**Comment :** Maybe, you haven't much done transformation geometry, in particular with dilations (also called homotheties) like δ (as named in the solution above) with a **negative ratio −1/2** as mentionned for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle). Begin by understanding what a dilation with ratio $r>1$ means and why images of lines transported are parallel line (a property shared by all affine mappings if you happen to know this name).

**Figure :**

[image]